# Retorno de função javascript dentro de outra função

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma chamada via ajax e retornando um array. Utilizando o console.log eu vejo o resultado da consulta. Mas o que eu preciso é chamar esse resultado dentro de outra função chart do google

```
quantityDaySurgeries = function(){
  var array = '';
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url:  getUrl + 'informations/dashboard',
    data: {datec:$("#datepicker_3").val(),dater:$("#datepicker_4").val() },
    success: function(data) {
      $.each( data.daysurgerys, function(index,element){
        array += '["'+element.day+'",'+element.quantity+','+element.pen+','+element.nop+'],';
      })     
    }
  });

  return array;
};
```

Se eu chamar ela assim não vem dados

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', '','',''],
    quantityDaySurgeries()
  ]);
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar? Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O `$.ajax` não irá executar o `success` antes do seu `return`, você pode trabalhar com promise ou com funções de callback para chegar ao resultado esperado.

> Exemplo: Promise

```
quantityDaySurgeries = function () {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        var array = '';
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: getUrl + 'informations/dashboard',
            data: { datec: $("#datepicker_3").val(), dater: $("#datepicker_4").val() },
            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data.daysurgerys, function (index, element) {
                    array += '["' + element.day + '",' + element.quantity + ',' + element.pen + ',' + element.nop + ']';

                })

                res(array);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                rej(err);
            }
        });
    })
};

// utilização

function drawVisualization() {
    quantityDaySurgeries().then(function (result) {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Month', '', '', ''],
            result
        ]);

        // o resto do seu código
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // deu erro..
    });
}
```

> Exemplo: Função de callback

```
quantityDaySurgeries = function (onSuccess, onError) {
        var array = '';
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: getUrl + 'informations/dashboard',
        data: { datec: $("#datepicker_3").val(), dater: $("#datepicker_4").val() },
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data.daysurgerys, function (index, element) {
                array += '["' + element.day + '",' + element.quantity + ',' + element.pen + ',' + element.nop + ']';

            })

            onSuccess(array);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            onError(err);
        }
    });
};

// utilização
function drawVisualization() {
    quantityDaySurgeries(function(result) {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Month', '', '', ''],
            result
        ]);

        // o resto do seu código
    }, function (err) {
        // erro...
    })
}
```

Comment: usei seu exemplo de promise mas o retorno não aparece dentro da função do chart, somente se der o console.log que eu vejo o resultado.

Comment: @marcelo_faria não sei como o chart funciona, mas em tese o processo para obter e trabalhar os dados é esse. Se vc executar com os dados inputados manualmente na função, ela funciona?

Comment: eu estava puxando do banco de dados e iterando array php direto nela e funciona normalmente. Ali vai ficar resultados assim ["11/11",0,0,0],["12/11",0,0,0],["13/11",3,2,1],["14/11",0,0,0],["15/11",0,0,0] ....mas como preciso depois fazer consultas de diferentes datas , estou usando o javascript para não precisar dar refresh na pagina para diferentes pesquisas e tal

Comment: @marcelo_faria atualizei a resposta. Testa novamente por favor.

Comment: Do jeito que voce fez agora esta voltando um array para cada item, não vai funcionar assim, porque so precisa retornar os itens separados por virgulas e dentro do colchetes  ["11/11",0,0,0],["12/11",0,0,0].... o código anterior ele retorna do jeito que precisa, so não esta exibindo os dados apenas chamando o RESULT, se chamar console.log(result) ele mostra os dados vindo certinhos, mas dentro da função ele não retorna nada

Comment: o problema so está sendo em exibir o retorno, os dados estão vindo certos, mas ele não exibe dentro da outra função chamando ele apenas como RESULT

Comment: @marcelo_faria onde vc colocou o console.log?

Comment: coloquei onde esta o RESULT, aí ele exibe os dados corretos, mas se tirar o console e deixar somente o RESULT não aparece as informações para gerar o grafico